# gnu make fails to find commands in ~/.local/bin

Tags: make, makefile

I have some commands places in `~/.local/bin`, and correctly added it to the path:

```
$ echo $PATH
~/.local/bin:~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
$ ls ~/.local/bin
dul-daemon        ipcluster      iptest       ...
$ type -a pelican
pelican is /home/juanlu/.local/bin/pelican
```

but even though I can place this lines in a GNU make recipe, it eventually fails to execute the command:

```
$ cat Makefile 
fail:
    @echo $$PATH
    @compgen -c | grep pelican
    @pelican --help
$ make fail
~/.local/bin:~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
pelican-import
pelican-themes
pelican-quickstart
pelican
make: pelican: Command not found
make: *** [fail] Error 127
```

I have tried to find the solution elsewhere but I don't even find a way to write a search query to put in Google that returns something meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `$PATH` contains the literal `~` instead of the real path. The `~/...` syntax is something specific to the shell; it is not expanded by glibc's `execvp()` function, for example.

Use absolute paths, as in `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:$PATH`

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much!